# Expand DataFrame using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm working with a feature set structured like the following, which has 150 features:

```
-1 45:1 55:1 67:1
1  55:1 65:1 89:1
```

How can I use pandas to expand this data set such that it's a full matrix or array with all 150 features? In other words in the first row feature 44 is 0, so I would like to use pandas to make something like:

```
[-1,0,0,0,...(44th entry)0,1,...
1,0,0,0,...(54th entry)0,1,...]
```

Basically I assume there is a way in pandas to do this so I don't write a for loop and generate a zeros matrix and have it fill in the values. Am I seeking to do something like this : [Fill a Pandas dataframe using information from another Pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15708434/fill-a-pandas-dataframe-using-information-from-another-pandas-dataframe) Or is there a better implementation since my problem seems less complex. Thanks as I am new to pandas.

Comment: I don't understand how your input data is structured, what type of object is that? Are the -1 and 1 at the beginning supposed to be indices?

Comment: no they are binary classifiers or imagine a matrix like [y|x1 x2 x3,...]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the data was in `svm_light` format so I used the approbate python module - problem solved!